# "uninitialized constant Authlogic"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

Just followed the Authlogic tutorial. I am getting "uninitialized constant Authlogic" when I try run the app. After searching, I can see that it has to do with gems/plugins but I can't find a solution.

Edit:

My UserSession model is:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it in your `environment.rb` file? If it is, did you restart your server?

If you're using Rails 3, is it in your `Gemfile`, and did you restart your server?

Most of all, did you install the gem?

Comment: I forgot to restart the server! I read it didn't need to be restarted in development mode so that wasn't in my mind at all. Thanks!

Comment: It happens to all of us! No worries